# Add an if alternative statement inside another if statement within a loop with php to create two links (one real and one empty)

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

First the problem:
My code is broken if I add an if alternative statement inside another if statment in a loop:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) : ?>
    <li>
        <?php $partner = the_field('industry_partner_links'); ?>
        <?php 
        if ($partner) :
            ?>
            <a href="<?php the_field('industry_partner_links'); ?>" target="_blank">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full' ); ?>
            </a>
            <?php 
        else :
            ?>
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full' ); ?>
            </a>
            <?php 
        endif;
        ?>
    </li>
```

My goal is to create a loop in my template to display some image (they have a URL that will direct to an image) based on a custom post in a Wordpress environment BUT, if the image doesn't have the link (ACF), the url will be empty (href=#").

Essentially, I created a section with my sponsors (image wrapped in a link) and I feed those images and URLs from the backend of WordPress using ACF (advanced custom field). Spoiler, it works.

Tha basic code in php:

```
<?php 

$args = [
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'orderby'          => 'title',
    'post_type'        => 'partner',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
];

if ( $posts = get_posts( $args ) ) {
    echo '<ul class="feed-industry-partners">';
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post ); 
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) : ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_field('industry_partner_links'); ?>" target="_blank">
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full' ); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }                   
    echo '</ul>';
}

?>
```

Any Idea why it is not working?

Comment: What's broken? What is the result of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you gave here I can guess that function `the_field('industry_partner_links')` does not return anything but it prints to output. So good news, your code is correct. The problem is with logic here. Variable `$partner = the_field('industry_partner_links');` will be always falsy. But there is a workaround with output buffering (but this is ugly solution): `<?php ob_start(); the_field('industry_partner_links'); $product = ob_get_flush(); ?>`. More proper way is to make some switch in function `the_field()` which will return value instead of printing it. Or maybe make another function which will do the same job but it will return the result, hm? :)

Comment: Exactly, the right snippet is:

if (get_field('industry_partner_links')) :